# Why does an lmer model converge in one experimental condition but not another?

Tags: mixed-model, assumptions, group-differences

I am new to using linear mixed-effects models. I have a dataset where participants (ID, N = 7973) completed two experimental conditions (A and B). A subset of participants are siblings and thus nested in families (famID, N = 6908).

```
omnibus_model <- lmer(Outcome ~ Var1*Var2*Cond + (Cond|ID) + (1|famID), data=df)
```

The omnibus model converges and indicates a significant three way interaction between Var1, Var2 and Cond. As a post-hoc, to better understand what is driving the omnibus model effect, I subsetted the data so that there is only one observation per ID.

```
condA <- df[which(df$condition=='A'),]
condA_model <- lmer(Outcome ~ Var1*Var2 + (1|famID), data=condA)
condB <- df[which(df$condition=='B'),]
condB_model <- lmer(Outcome ~ Var1*Var2 + (1|famID), data=condB)
```

condA_model converges; condB_model does not. In condB_model "famID (Intercept)" variance is estimated at 0. In the condA_model, I get a small, but non-zero estimate (variance=0.001479). I know I could get an estimate of the fixed effect of interest in condition A versus B by a different method(such as randomly selecting one sibling per family for the analysis and not using random effects), but I am concerned that this differential convergence pattern may indicate differences between the conditions that would influence the interpretation of the omnibus model effect.

What difference in the two conditions could causing the model in one subset not to converge? How would I test for the possible differences in my data? Shouldn't the random effect of famID be identical in both subsets and thus equally able to be estimated in both post-hoc models?

Comment: Why have you subsetted the data ? This WILL cause a reduction in statistical power and may result in convergence problems (as you have discovered), with no benefit whatsoever -   the full model with the 2 and 3 way interactions and main effects  is all you need.

Comment: I subsetted the data because Cond variable in the example is actually two interacting variables (2 levels of difficulty crossed 3 levels of valence) and I wanted to use one of the six conditions of interest to look at a fully between-subjects mediation model. 5/6 of the subset models will converge when subset in this way, but not my 1 condition of interest. I want to understand why that might be; I don't understand why the power in one of the conditions would be less than the other 5? I'm concerned that there may be a model assumption, like equal variance between groups that might not be met?

Comment: What is the purpose of your model ? Unequal variances is not necessarily a problem. When you have an interaction, the worst thing you can do is split the data. There are many reasons for convergence problems. Are you sure it hasn't converged ? What is the actual error(s). Perhaps it simply converged to a singular fit because there is insufficient variation in the data (something which often happens when you split up the dataset).

Comment: I get a singular fit warning and the "famID (Intercept)" variance is estimated at 0. Is there a way to determine is this is caused by insufficient variation in the data in that condition? I was planning to follow-up on the omnibus interaction by using the performance in the one condition of interest as a mediator (to allow all the  variables in the model to differ between subjects). However, if there is not enough variability in performance in that condition, it seems like that may not be the best option. The fact that I get a singular fit here means I have a singular fit for mediation path A.